# Why does my onClick not work inside my activity?

Tags: java, android

I have tried EVERYTHING under the damn sun to get this to work and I can't figure it out.

My activity responds to `onTouchEvent` but not to `onClick`

I've tried

`implements View.OnClickListener`

I've tried

every other thing to get my activity to accept a click but nothing happens.

What I have currently is this code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //removes title bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //sets view to full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


       RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.muhLayout);
       rl.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

My problem with the above code is when I access the RelativeLayout, I get a nullpointerexception.
I don't know why.. my layout exists, it is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

in XML.

I tried adding `@+id/....` and referencing it that way, same thing, I get an NPE.

my `onClick` method looks like this

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        pixelColor = Color.RED;
        PixelParticle pp = new PixelParticle(this, x, y, 50, 50, pixelColor);
        setContentView(pp);
    }
```

PixelParticle extends a View and uses `onDraw` method override to draw. This all works perfectly when I use `onTouchEvent`. But I need `onClick` to work.

Can someone help me figure this out?

One last thing.. when I use `onTouchEvent` and my bitmap is drawn, what exactly is it drawn on?
The image being drawn is a `View` since `PixelParticle` extends view and overrides `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` to do the drawing. I assume it is RelativeLayout, which is a subclass of View, but I want to make sure.

Comment: Where are you inflating your layout?  You must use either setContentView() or LayoutInflater.  This, `RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.muhLayout);` will always lead to an NPE since findViewById will return null.  I think you should do a couple of hello world tutorials.

Comment: Shayan, as you see above, I already AM doing that..

Simon, could you show me how to use layoutinflater in this situation?

Comment: I don't know what "this situation" is.  Why can't you use setContentView()?

Comment: I'm using setContentView in my `onTouchEvent` method, it's how the PixelParticle is displayed. If I use it in the `onCreate` method as you suggest, my Pixel will not display.

Comment: I'm afraid to say you have completely confused yourself.  I really do recommend doing some basic tutorials and reading the documentation for setContentView.  It is NOT related to how/where a custom view draws itself.  You haven't explained what you are tying to do but it seems to me that you should add your custom view to your layout and use setContentView in onCreate but without knowing what you are trying to do, hard to say.

Comment: You should also understand what findViewById is not working for you.  It **will* work following setContentView (assuming that your layout is correct).  http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html